# Expanding ubuntu disk (while having the message DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON)

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

In the image bellow I want to expand the ubuntu into the free space. make them one.
I have the message "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON" for the past few months.
how can I do that merge those partitions, the resize option only allow me to decrease the size and not increasing...

[image]

Comment: "DISK IS LIKELY TO BY FAIL SOON" is not related to the partition changing. It usually means that the disk has detected errors, has corrected them but either is running out of spare sectors to remaps broken sectors to, or has detected an increase in errors.

Comment: As to part 2: I see you have space BEFORE the partition you are trying to expand, and a screenshot with free space AFTER...

Comment: Disk is likely to fail soon is a S.M.A.R.T. message indicating the likelihood of a physical failure of the disk.

Comment: Do not bother partitioning this disk. Replace it quickly before it fails completely. Partition work means much disk access and will only speed up the failure of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Check the S.M.A.R.T. attributes of the disk:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl -A /dev/<put your disk name here>
```

If you see non zero values for this fields:

```
5   (Reallocated_Sector_Ct)
184 (End-to-End_Error)
187 (Reported_Uncorrect)
197 (Current_Pending_Sector)
198 (Offline_Uncorrectable)
```

it means your disk most likely to die soon.

Comment: `<put your disk name here>` How to know/find disk name,

Comment: Never mind found way to know disk name `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 0):

Resizing partitions can be done at the end of the partition, so you would have to move the Ubuntu partition to the beginning of the free space and then resize it.

That said, it may be easier to simply create a new partition in the empty space and use it as your /home partition. There are tutorials online on how to switch your /home partition location without data loss.

I would go this path also because of the likelihood of your disk failing soon (BACKUP!). Moving partitions is a disk intensive activity and might increase the risk of failure.

Simply creating a new ext4 partition and using it as home is potentially less disk intensive.